# Python Pandas hdfstore's select(where='') return unqualified results

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

When I query a large hdfstore file (>10G) like this:

```
hdf = pd.HDFStore('raw_sample_storage.h5')
nrows = hdf.get_storer('raw_sample_all').nrows
chunksize = 300000

for i in xrange(nrows//chunksize + 1):
    chunk = hdf.select('raw_sample_all', where=[pd.Term('node_id', '==', 1)], start=i*chunksize, stop=(i+1)*chunksize)
    print chunk.head(2)
```

**I got results where most entries' node_id is 1, but some entries have node_id other than 1. So is it a hdfstore glitch, or I did something wrong?**

Here is part of the results you can see there are some entries with node_id other than 1.

```
                 time   GW_time  node_id      X      Y      Z  status  seq  \
2 2013-10-22 17:20:58  39821888        1  16927  21438  22722       0   34   
6 2013-10-22 17:20:58  39822144        1  16927  21438  22722       0   35   

   rssi  lqi  
2   -46   48  
6   -51   48  
                      time   GW_time  node_id      X      Y      Z  status  \
300002 2013-10-22 17:30:50  59223744        3  19915  20840  22003       0   
300006 2013-10-22 17:30:50  59224000        3  19913  20844  22002       0   

        seq  rssi  lqi  
300002   46   -64   50  
300006   47   -64   48  
                      time   GW_time  node_id      X      Y      Z  status  \
600000 2013-10-22 17:40:55  79050561        1  17612  22536  21198       0   
600004 2013-10-22 17:40:55  79050817        1  17613  22535  21201       0   

        seq  rssi  lqi  
600000   55   -67   46  
600004   56   -67   49  
                      time   GW_time  node_id      X      Y      Z  status  \
900003 2013-10-22 17:50:44  98345217        4  18934  20212  19364       0   
900007 2013-10-22 17:50:44  98345473        4  18935  20212  19359       0   

        seq  rssi  lqi  
900003   32   -60   46  
900007   33   -60   48  
                       time    GW_time  node_id      X      Y      Z  status  \
1200003 2013-10-22 18:00:31  117600065        1  17618  22541  21191       0   
1200007 2013-10-22 18:00:31  117600321        1  17620  22538  21187       0   

         seq  rssi  lqi  
1200003  111   -66   47  
1200007  112   -66   48
```

Noticing row 300002 is an unwanted result, I try to select node 1 around that particular area like this:

```
chunk = hdf.select('raw_sample_all', start=300002-20, stop=300002+20, 
                       where=[pd.Term('node_id', '==', 1)])
```

Only node 3 is returned in the result:

```
                   time     GW_time  node_id    X      Y       Z status seq rssi lqi
299982  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59222464    3   19912   20838   22003   0   41  -64 48
299986  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59222720    3   19912   20838   22003   0   42  -64 48
299990  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59222976    3   19913   20840   22007   0   43  -64 50
299994  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223232    3   19913   20840   22007   0   44  -64 50
299998  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223488    3   19915   20840   22003   0   45  -64 48
300002  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223744    3   19915   20840   22003   0   46  -64 50
300006  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224000    3   19913   20844   22002   0   47  -64 48
300010  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224256    3   19913   20844   22002   0   48  -64 50
300014  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224512    3   19914   20844   22010   0   49  -64 49
300018  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224768    3   19914   20844   22010   0   50  -64 50
```

**Then I try use index instead of start/stop like this:**

```
chunk = hdf.select('raw_sample_all', 
                   where=[pd.Term('index', '>=', 300002-20),
                          pd.Term('index', '<=', 300002+20),
                          pd.Term('node_id', '==', 1)])
```

And this time it returned correct results:

```
                time        GW_time node_id  X       Y      Z   status seq rssi lqi
299984  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59222593    1   17613   22543   21203   0   42  -80 48
299988  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59222849    1   17613   22543   21203   0   43  -81 48
299992  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223105    1   17610   22547   21194   0   44  -81 48
299996  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223361    1   17610   22547   21194   0   45  -81 47
300000  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223617    1   17609   22545   21190   0   46  -81 45
300004  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59223873    1   17609   22545   21190   0   47  -81 49
300008  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224129    1   17606   22547   21199   0   48  -81 48
300012  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224385    1   17606   22547   21199   0   49  -81 48
300016  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224641    1   17607   22548   21191   0   50  -81 49
300020  2013-10-22 17:30:50 59224897    1   17607   22548   21191   0   51  -80 48
```

I guess I might walk around this problem with selection on index, but I am not completely sure because the method with start/stop also get the correct results most of the time, so even though the method with index got it right where start/stop failed, it might fail somewhere else.

And I would really like the start/stop method to work, because it is much faster, and I have a large data set, a slow method is really time-consuming.

BTW, In case you are wondering, I cannot use 'chunksize' like this:

```
df = hdf.select('raw_sample_all',chunksize=300000, where="node_id==1")
for chunk in df:
    print chunk.head(2)
```

Every time I try chunksize I got a MemoryError like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587026/when-reading-huge-hdf5-file-with-pandas-read-hdf-why-do-i-still-get-memory).
Struggling with many problems, Pandas is really tough for a newbie like me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was a recently fixed bug in `PyTables`, see the related issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9676). In effect on some larger stores the indexers where not computed correctly when using a `where` and `start/stop`.

You will need to update to `PyTables` 3.2, then re-write the store itself. You can either recreate it how you did the first time, or use [ptrepack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#compression)

Comment: I use anaconda, and I cannot upgrade with `conda update pytables` , it says "already installed". Then I tried `pip install --upgrade tables`, it says `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'hdf5dll.lib' ... ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation. ` I searched my harddisk, and couldn't find hdf5dll.lib file.